# What does the -nh in the default emacs grep command (grep -nh -e) mean?

Tags: grep

Question is in the title.

Emacs default grep command is:

`grep -nh -e`

I know `-e` means match pattern. What is -nh?

Comment: It's very important to know that most shell commands have manual pages (e.g. `man grep`) which contain full details of their options; and failing that, it's also extremely common for `-h` or `--help` to provide a usage summary as well (e.g. `grep -h`). It's very uncommon for this kind of information to be undocumented.

Comment: @phils I did search the grep manual but I couldn't find an answer. Also: Isn't it the case that many SO questions can be answered in man pages but that the point of the platform is to provide an alternative (with more context)

Comment: That's very true, although those questions do tend to be "how to I do a thing (for which there happens to be an option)?" more than "what does this option do?".  I was just trying to make sure you knew how to look up these things without resorting to SO.  Perhaps the bit you were missing was that single-character options like `-n` and `-h` can almost always be combined into (in this case) `-nh`, so perhaps you weren't looking for `-n` and `-h` individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be stated in the man pages for [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

> **-n**, ***--line-number***
>                 <sub>Prefix  each  line  of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.
>                 (***-n*** is specified by POSIX.)</sub>
>
> **-h**, ***--no-filename***
>                 <sub>Suppress the prefixing of file names on output.  This is the default  when  there
>                 is only one file (or only standard input) to search.</sub>

↳ https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Answer (score 0):

The Emacs default is -nH not -nh. The capital H tells grep to display the results with the file names as a clickable link. The small "h" tells grep not to display a filename.